# AMI Asterisk Manager Interface Originate Issues with Outbound calls

Tags: asterisk

I have a puzzling issue with my AMI implementation (totally new to this). I can successfully initiate calls to other extensions on my network. However, when I make outbound calls, they fail. I've installed Elastix using Asterisk 1.8.7.0 and FreePBX 2.8.1. On the outbound call, all I get is "goodbye" once the call has been placed. It successfully places the call but somehow it's not allowed by Asterisk?

Also note that all calls work well when using any SIP phone both to internal and external destinations! Therefore must be something I'm missing in the AMI implementation.

My manager.conf:

```
[user]
secret = 1111
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
read = all
write = all
```

Gave all permissions for read and write just to try and catch this one

```
My code (using Asterisk.NET):
Dim originate As New Asterisk.NET.Manager.Action.OriginateAction
originate.Channel = "SIP/106" 'This is the originating extension
originate.Context = "default" 'other option is - from-internal
originate.Exten =  7859855452
originate.Priority = 1

originate.CallerId = "106" 'This is the originating extension number
originate.Async = True
originate.Timeout = 30000

Dim response As New Asterisk.NET.Manager.Response.ManagerResponse
response = manager.SendAction(originate)
```

Comment: SOLVED!

Was using the wrong context all along!

Changed it to from-internal and worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

As per latest updates in Asterisk 1.8 if you are originating on external peer/trunk then channel variable will be like **SIP/peer/extension** instead of SIP/extension@peer